# Spring Boot & OAuth2.0: At least one redirect_uri must be registered with the client

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

So I login to an app and go to an external feature, which demands another login (all within the app). Now it has become impossible to log into that external feature as it throws error (code 400):

```
OAuth Error. error="invalid_request", error_description="At least one redirect_uri must be registered with the client."
```

This error is thrown whenever I'm using the app or try to login to the external feature directly.

I had upgraded Spring Boot in a project to 1.5.22 from 1.4.1, which may have caused this. After downgrading back Spring Boot to 1.4.1 the problem was gone.

Then I tried updating Spring Boot to 1.5.22 again and additionally included this in application.configuration:

```
security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=https://page.com
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=https://page.com
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
```

It didn't help. Then in browser's Network tab I noticed redirect_url parameter in Query String Parameters, which differed from the one I specified. It was something like:

```
https://page.com/oauth-authorized/app
```

I updated application.configuration as above. However, nothing has changed.

How to proceed?

Some code:

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Autowired
  private TokenStore tokenStore;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("clientDetailsServiceImpl")
  private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

  @Autowired
  private TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer;

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    endpoints
        .tokenStore(tokenStore)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .tokenServices(tokenServices)
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer)
        .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/api/oauth/token")
        .pathMapping("/oauth/check_token", "/api/oauth/check_token")
        .pathMapping("/oauth/authorize", "/api/oauth/authorize")
        .pathMapping("/oauth/error", "/api/oauth/error");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
  }
}
=================================================================================================

@Service
@Primary
public class ClientDetailsServiceImpl implements ClientDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private ClientRepository clientRepository;

  @Override
  public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {
    Client client = clientRepository.findOneByClientId(clientId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchClientException(
            String.format("Client with clientId=%s was not found", clientId)));

    return new com.app.auth.domain.ClientDetails(client);
  }

}
```

Edit: After downgrading Spring Boot once again the problem seems gone but it's not much of a fix.

Answer (score 0):

After authentication, you may need to contact the resource owner and ask for support and then redirect to your client application or you may redirect to client application directly.
for that, add `redirectUris` in your Authorization server config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("client_id").secret("client_secret").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .scopes("read").authorities("CLIENT").redirectUris("http://localhost:8090/your_redirect_URL");
    }
}
```